# How to create custom function in javascript that looks like a dot notation? e.g., str.getFirstIndex();

Tags: javascript

I was looking on the code on our team project, and was wondering if I can make it better, *"clean and easy to understand"*.

I've done a research but I couldn't found any, maybe Its because I don't know the terminologies use?

Anyway here is the code:

```
var num = 10000;

function toShortMoney(num) {
    var thousand = Math.pow(10, 3),
        million = Math.pow(10, 6),
        billion = Math.pow(10, 9),
        negative = false,
        money = '0',
        str = '';

    str = num.toString();
    if(str.indexOf('-') > -1) {
        negative = true;
        str = str.slice(1);
        num = str.valueOf(str);
    }

    if(num < million && num >= thousand) { //thousand
        num = (Math.floor(num / thousand)).toFixed(0);
        money = num + 'K';
    }
    else if(num < billion && num >= million) { //million
        num = (num / million).toFixed(2).replace(/(\.?0+$)/,'');
        money = num + 'M';
    }
    else {
        money = Math.floor(num).toFixed(0);
    }

    if(negative)
        return '($' + money + ')';

    return '$' + money;
}
```

Initially I can access toShortMoney by putting the variable num as a parameter,
but How could I access toShortMoney by doing a dot notation like function?

> e.g., num.toShortMoney(); //returns $10k

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956935/extending-primitive-javascript-types), although, given the terminology being used, you wouldn't have known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this method to be available on any number object, you'll have to add the method to `Number`'s prototype.

```
Number.prototype.toShortMoney = function() {
  // in the context of being called on a number, the number will
  // not be an argument, but you access it via this eg.:
  return '$' + this;
};
```

However, some people feel like adding methods to the prototypes of the native classes is bad practice (except for polyfilling).. But I would say mostly that's true for library projects.

Good luck

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Comment: @guest271314 maybe because you haven't adjusted the code? by looking at arnorhs code there is no num object since there is no parameters anymore . thats way **num** will be undefined

Comment: **If you want this method to be available on any number object ?** so this code will work by appending .toShortMoney on any number object?

Comment: I updated my answer to describe how you need to access the number via `this` of the called method.

Comment: I got your point now . And thanks for the new idea _"polyfilling"_ , I'll read this one to prevent bad practices :)

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust `num` to `this` within `toShortMoney`, you can also extend `String.prototype` to accept wither `Number` or `String`

```
function toShortMoney() {
    var thousand = Math.pow(10, 3),
        million = Math.pow(10, 6),
        billion = Math.pow(10, 9),
        negative = false,
        money = '0',
        str = '';

    num = this;
    str = num.toString();
    if(str.indexOf('-') > -1) {
        negative = true;
        str = str.slice(1);
        num = str.valueOf(str);
    }

    if(num < million && num >= thousand) { //thousand
        num = (Math.floor(num / thousand)).toFixed(0);
        money = num + 'K';
    }
    else if(num < billion && num >= million) { //million
        num = (num / million).toFixed(2).replace(/(\.?0+$)/,'');
        money = num + 'M';
    }
    else {
        money = Math.floor(num).toFixed(0);
    }

    if(negative)
        return '($' + money + ')';

    return '$' + money;
}

String.prototype.toShortMoney = Number.prototype.toShortMoney = toShortMoney
```